ContourPlot is not accurately capturing contour lines
Even with such simple functions
ContourPlot[x^2/4 + y^2 - 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourLabels -> All]

ContourPlot[(x^2/4 + y^2 - 1)^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourLabels -> All, Contours -> 0, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

ContourPlot isn't able to capture the line for (x^2/4 + y^2 - 1)^2 == 0, but is perfect for the lines for x^2/4 + y^2 - 1, why?


From the help: "Contours f(x,y)==0 for functions where f(x,y)>=0 are always poorly detected".
If you set x=0 and plot y, you see that this is the case:
Plot[(x^2/4 + y^2 - 1)^2 /. x -> 0, {y, 0.9, 1.1}]



where did you find this "help": Contours f(x,y)==0 for functions where f(x,y)>=0 are always poorly detected

Look at "ContourPlot / Possible Issues"

There is a workaround, at least for the case under consideration.
ListPlot[{x, y} /.FindInstance[(x^2/4 + y^2 - 1)^2 == 0 && RealAbs[x] <= 2 && 
RealAbs[y] <= 2, {x, y}, Reals, 25000]]



Note that Contours -> 0 indicates that you want no contours. Use Contours -> {0}; however, as Daniel points out, that won't work for this type of function. Instead, pick a small value.
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ContourPlot[
 (x^2/4 + y^2 - 1)^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Contours -> {0.0001},
 ContourShading -> None,
 WorkingPrecision -> 10,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 PlotRange -> 2.1]


The 0 contour would fall between the two 0.0001 contours.

That approaches may mislead sometimes. For example, ContourPlot[  100*RealAbs[-x^2 + y] + RealAbs[1 - x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},   Contours -> {0.0001}, ContourShading -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 10,   PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotRange -> 2.1] produces an empty plot, whereas ListPlot of the result of FindInstace produces the correct result in this case.
